# Does inheritance imply a deep copy of memory?

Tags: c++

I have a class `foo` and `bar`. `foo` has a resource. When `bar` inherits from `foo` will it too have a deep copy of the memory? Or do I have to call the constructor of `foo` from `bar`s default-constructor?

```
class foo
{
    char *item;
    public:
        foo() : item(new char[5]) {}
};

class bar : public foo {};
```

Comment: The base class constructor will get called automatically and bar will have it's own 5 element array. Each instance of a bar is also a foo, so they each have their own arrays. Inheritance isn't "sharing" inheritance means it is itself and all the things it inherited. Put in some print statements in the constructor and you'll see it happen!

Comment: What do you mean "deep copy"? Inheritance doesn't "copy" anything.

Comment: In fact when you create an instance of `bar`, it can't share (or copy) "the" instance of `foo` - there may not be an instance of `foo` or there may be many. What is "shared" (at compile time) is a description or specification of a `foo` - a `bar` is like a `foo` except for these additions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derived class has:

```
All the members of base class + the additional members in derived class
```

The order of calling of constructors is well defined, the base class constructor is always called before the derived constructor. Depending on how you use the [member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361), either the default base class constructor or the parameterized version gets called.

But it's always Base class constructor followed by Derived class constructor. So not sure what your second Q is.

---

And just to be precise, Please remove the `char *` member and use `std::string`.

```
class foo
{
    //char *item;     ---------------->  Erroneous, difficult to handle
    std::string item;

    ....
```

Comment: The question was somewhat hard to understand, but I believe he may have deliberately chosen a `char*` for the example because it is a pointer, and he is confused about that aspect of it. That's my guess based on his use of the phrase "deep copy", anyway.

Comment: @JBentley: Perhaps, or perhaps OP used `char *` and then got confused about its handling. I think it's best to mention the `std::string` anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the memory layout as two sub-structs `foo` and `bar` gathered in one named `bar`.

Your bar class will look like that in memory:

```
*******
foo members:
-char* item (sizeof(char*)
*******
bar members:
*******
```

When you will create a new `bar`, you will reserve memory for these two structures. 
In your case this will reserve enough memory for the char* which is probably 4 bytes in case of a x86 compiler.

In a normal usecase, `bar`'s constructor will contains everything related to `bar`'s member. `bar`'s constructor can also call "manually" `foo`'s constructor within the initialization list or a raw call. Otherwise the compiler will call the `foo`'s default constructor for you.